# Removing Users when using AD Security

Tags: plasticscm

Anyone know how to remove users in PlasticSCM when the server is configured to use Active Directory security?

Comment: turns out you need to use the command line tools:<br/>
--to list the users: cm li <br/>
--to remove old users: cm du username <br/>
--to add a new user: cm au <br/>

Answer (score 1):

The cm au/du commands are meant to activate or deactivate users.

But users are not 'added' to Plastic as such.

When a user does an operation in Plastic, it will be automatically added provided you have enough licences and the user has permissions to access the system (you've set the correct ACLs).

Suppose you just have a 20 users license:

- You simply install the license (copy the plasticd.lic file)
- Then the first user access the system, it will be 'activated'
- Second user accesss, second 'activation', it happens automatically
- Then suppose you already have 20 developers using Plastic and one of them leaves and a new one enters, then you have to deactivate the old one and activate the new one, but only then.

Hope it helps.